# javascript and HTML5 draw video into canvas

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a video into the canvas in javascript and HTML5 (like an intro video for a game) which is working fine on the web browser but is not working on android, so I'm not sure if I making a mistake somewhere or this is not supported on mobile devices.

Here is the code:

```
//create canvas and get 2d context
var canvas = document.getElementById('introVid');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// allow fullscreen
function fullscreen() {
  var el = canvas;
  if (el.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    el.webkitRequestFullScreen(); //chrome
  } else {
    el.mozRequestFullScreen(); //firefox
  }
}
canvas.addEventListener("click", fullscreen); //enable fullscreen onClick

//draw the video into canvas
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
  video.play(); // start playing
  update(); //start rendering
});

function update() {
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 300, 150);
  requestAnimationFrame(update); //wait the browser be ready for next frame
};
```

Here a working demo on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/h1hjp0Lp/122/

Comment: Did you see any error messages?

Comment: there are not errors in the console in the remote device is also working in the browser simulation of the mobile device that chrome is doing. I tried also to install firefox on the mobile device same result. So I'm assuming now that is not supported.

Comment: Strange issue indeed...
Check on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats
The compatible video / audio formats with mobile devices: <video>: H.264 and AAC in MP4 and <video>:  H.264 and MP3 in MP4 should be fine